# how to register xib (UITableViewCell) to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

if using storyboard and add component tableview it would like this

```
class RestaurantViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var restaurantTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        restaurantTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PackageTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PackageTableViewCell")
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using storyboard then why using xib? instead of xib use custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

i already found how to register xib to the UITableViewController. if using storyboard and linked it to the code. we can use the name of the initial component (UITableView).

but if using UITableViewController, self is the View Controller. here is the code:

```
class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PackageTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PackageTableViewCell")
    }
}
```